# Regular Expression Excluding a Start String

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using a regular expression like

```
<cfset a = ReFind("DESCRIBE\+[^>]*>", myResult.Header, 1, true) />
```

If I need that this Regular Expression should not include `DESCRIBE+` in calculating the LEN and Position values. How should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DESCRIBE+ is 9 characters, cant you just add / subtract this number and do math.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset a = ReFind("DESCRIBE\+([^>]*>)", myResult.Header, 1, true) />

<cfif ArrayLen(a.pos) GT 1><!--- match found! --->
  <cfset afterDescribePosition = a.pos[2]>
  <cfset afterDescribeLength = a.len[2]>
</cfif>
```

ReFind (when the fourth param is set to true, as you have done) will return a structure with two values (pos and len).  Each of these is an array.  If you don't have any capture groups ( parenthesis) within your regex, then both of these arrays will be just one value long - representing the full regex match.  If you have capture groups defined (as I do in my example), then the subsequent values in each array will correspond with the respective capture group.  In my example, there is only one capture group, so each array will be of length 2 (assuming there is a match).  The values at the second position will therefore relate to the first capture group.

[ReFind](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e9a.html)

Answer (score 0):

If ColdFusion supports look behind, then you can use `(?<=DESCRIBE\+)[^>]*>`

Comment: I am pretty sure Java does - and ColdFusion can easily wrap it

Comment: Why the down vote? This does what was asked, and it does it as a regular expression.